# Hoping HTML5 and CSS3 give neater answer to equal-height columns and vertically centred content

Tags: html, css

This question or a variation of it has been asked many times before (my eyes are hurting with all the solutions I've read), but a lot of what I read was quite old, and I am hoping that maybe HTML5 and CSS3 might offer a neater solution.

The problem is a common one.  I have a lump of HTML content (paragraphs of text), which I want to take up a proportion of the screen (say 70%), and I want another column alongside this, in which I want to place a button, which is vertically centered relative to the text.

Although I have listed equal-height columns in the title of this question, this isn't strictly necessary because both columns are the same colour as the background, and so it wouldn't matter if one column were shorter than the other.

Vertical alignment is such a common requirement that I can't believe, with the new shiny mark-up we now have, there isn't a simple solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as would any recommendations of books I might buy to get up-to-date on HTML5 and CSS3 (so I can stop pestering StackOverflow members hopefully :-) ).

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

Comment: Look into Flexible Box (Flexbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle;`

```
.left {
    width:70%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.left p {
    width:32%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.right {
    width:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WSrNm/)

Or you could use Flexbox with `align-items:center` or `align-items:stretch` depending on what you want. [**Article**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Mmm... don't know what I am doing wrong, but the vertical-align:middle on the right column seems to be being ignored (the content stays at the top).

Comment: Have a live example? My Fiddle works for you, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this isn't much help, but check out this link: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

It has been very helpful for me.